# Two different registers having the same address

Tags: c

I am writing code to program a UART chip. The transmit and receive registers both have an address offset of 0x00. How then is it possible to access both registers?

Comment: Because one is read-only and the other is write-only, the circuitry is "wired" so that they appear at the same address. Why would you want to read the UART data that you have just sent? You know what you wrote!

Comment: In other words, when you write to it you write to one register, when you read from it you read from the other register.

Answer (score 1):

The two registers are not each readable and writable from code.  The UART transmit register is write-only.  The UART receive register is read-only. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345144/two-different-register-is-having-same-offset-address#comment64103882_38345144).

The hardware uses the read/write control as a bit, like an address bit, to distinguish register access.

This means the code cannot directly read what was written.  Nor can code directly write to the receive register.

---

In rare cases, should code need to read the contents of the UART transmit register, a copy in a shadow memory could be used.

```
static unsigned char UART_write_shadow;

void UART_transmit_write(unsigned char x) {
  *UART_transmit_register_address = x;
  UART_write_shadow = x;
}

unsigned char UART_transmit_read(void) {
  return UART_write_shadow;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for my answers